# AES, 128 and 256 Invalid Key Length

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++, aes-gcm

I am trying to encrypt a text using Crypto++. It worked well last time when using AES CTR, but now when using CBC or GCM the max key length I can use is 32 bits??

The code that handles the encryption:

```
string xAESPlain, xAESCipher;
AutoSeededRandomPool xRng;

byte xAESKey[128]; // Doesnt Work has to be 32 or 16
byte xAESIv[128];

xRng.GenerateBlock(xAESKey, sizeof(xAESKey));
xRng.GenerateBlock(xAESIv, sizeof(xAESIv));

CBC_Mode< AES >::Encryption E;
E.SetKeyWithIV(xAESKey, sizeof(xAESKey), xAESIv);

StringSource ss(xAESPlain, true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(E,
        new StringSink(xAESCipher)
    )
);
```

When running this Crypto++ throws an `Exception`:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CryptoPP::InvalidKeyLength'
  what():  AES/CBC: 128 is not a valid key length
```

Note that the same thing happens when using the example.zip provided in the Wiki(and changing the key length to 256 or 128)

Any ideas why the `Exception` is being thrown?

Comment: *"The same happens when using the example.zip provided in the Wiki"* - I doubt the wiki provides an example that uses 128-byte keys. If you can cite it, then I can fix it though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Bytes are usually octets (8 bits). AES is specified for 128-bit block size or 16 bytes which is also the size of the IV. AES key sizes may be 128-bit, 192-bit or 256-bit or 16 byte, 24 byte or 32 byte respectively. They can't be different from those. So use this for AES-256:

```
byte xAESKey[32];
byte xAESIv[16];
```

This should have nothing to do with the mode of operation.

Answer (score 2):

It is little bit better and more safely initialize block size and key in this way:

```
unsigned char iv[ CryptoPP::AES::BLOCKSIZE ];
unsigned char keyq[ CryptoPP::AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH ];
```

CryptoPP also have constants like CryptoPP::AES::MIN_KEYLENGTH and etc.